# Error al realizar inserción de datos (inserta dos veces el registro)

Tags: php, ajax, json

procedo a explicar el problema que me esta pasando, tengo un formulario que se encarga de generar un QR con datos que consigue de una persona luego de realizar la respectiva búsqueda. El formulario esta validado para que no deje enviar datos vacíos.

Cuando algún dato este vació lo valido con php y si están vacíos envió un json vació y con ajax me encargo de mostrar el error de que no debe mandar datos vacíos.

Dicho esto, el problema se presenta que haciendo pruebas, en lo que envió el formulario con datos vacíos me muestra el alert sin problemas, y cuando lleno el formulario y mando a generar el QR lo genera sin problemas también, pero cuando reviso la tabla, resulta que me inserta dos veces el registro. Eso solo pasa cuando mando el formulario primero con datos vacíos, porque cuando lleno de una vez el form y envió los datos, se inserta una sola vez el registro sin problema.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

PHP:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
 if(!empty($_POST['id_p']) && !empty($_POST['names']) && !empty($_POST['apellidos']) && !empty($_POST['cedula']) && !empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['grado']) && !empty($_POST['fecha_grado'])){
   sleep(1);
   $db = new Conexion();
   $id = $_POST['id_p'];
   $n = $_POST['names'];
   $ape = $_POST['apellidos'];
   $ced = $_POST['cedula'];
   $est = $_POST['city'];
   $cnt = $_POST['grado'];
   $fecha = FechaReversa($_POST['fecha_grado']);

   $validar = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM tkd_certificado WHERE idpersona = ? AND id_cinturon = ? LIMIT 1");
   $params = array($id,$cnt);
   $validar->execute($params);
    if($db->rows($validar)>0){
      echo json_encode(array('datos'=>'cinturon_existe'));
    }else{
      $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT abreviatura FROM tkd_estados WHERE tkd_estado = ? LIMIT 1");
      $sql->execute(array($est));
      $row = $db->recorrer($sql)['abreviatura'];

      $grado = $db->prepare("SELECT cinturon FROM tkd_cinturon WHERE idcinturon = ? LIMIT 1");
      $grado->execute(array($cnt));
      $result = $db->recorrer($grado)['cinturon'];

      $ruta_png = 'views/app/images/qr/';
      $content_qr = 'Persona: ' . ' ' . $n . ' ' . $ape . '-' . ' ';
      $content_qr.= 'Cedula: ' . ' ' . $ced . '-' . ' ';
      $content_qr.= 'Estado: ' . ' ' . $row . '-' . ' ';
      $content_qr.= 'Grado: ' . ' ' . $result . ' - ' . 'Fecha del grado: ' . ' ' . $_POST['fecha_grado'] . ' ';
      $content_qr.= 'Serial del certificado: ' . ' ' . $row . '-' . $id . '-' . $cnt;
      $fileName = 'qr_file'.Encrypt($ced). $id . $fecha . date('d-m-Y'). Encrypt(time()) . rand(0,9999) .  '.png';

      $PathFinal = $ruta_png.$fileName;
      $serial = $row . '-' . $id . '-' . $cnt;
      $level = QR_ECLEVEL_H;
      $frameSize = 5;

      if(!file_exists($PathFinal)){
        QRcode::png($content_qr, $PathFinal, $level, $frameSize);
        $insertQr = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tkd_certificado(examen,serial_,qr,id_persona,id_cinturon)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
        $content = array($fecha,$serial,$fileName,$id,$cnt);
        if($insertQr->execute($content)){
          echo json_encode(array('error'=>false,'qr'=>$PathFinal,'id'=>$id,'cint'=>$cnt));
        }else{
          echo json_encode(array('error'=>true, 'mensaje'=>$insertQr->errorInfo()[2]));
        }
      } else {
        echo json_encode(array('qr'=>'qr_existe'));
      }
    }
   } else {
    echo json_encode(array('qr'=>'empty'));
   }
  } else {
   header('location:?view=index');
  }
?>
```

JS:

```
 function GenerarQr(){
  var view;
 jQuery(document).on('submit','#generar_qr', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

jQuery.ajax({
  url:'ajax.php?mode=qr',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  beforeSend: function(){
    $('#on_qr').text('Generando');
    $('#on_qr').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
})
.done(function(r){
  if(r.qr == 'empty'){
    view = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-fill alert-close alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">';
    view += '<center><h3>Todos los campos deben estar llenos</h3></center></div>';
    $('#response_qr').html(view);
    $('#on_qr').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#on_qr').text('Generar');
  } else if(r.qr == 'cinturon_existe'){
    view = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-fill alert-close alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">';
    view += '<center><h3>Esta persona ya posee un cinturon de este grado</h3></center></div>';
    $('#response_qr').html(view);
    $('#on_qr').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#on_qr').text('Generar');
  } else if(r.qr == 'qr_existe'){
    view = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-fill alert-close alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">';
    view += '<center><h3>Ya existe un QR con estos datos</h3></center></div>';
    $('#response_qr').html(view);
    $('#on_qr').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#on_qr').text('Generar');
  } else if(r.error == true){
    view = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-fill alert-close alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">';
    view += '<center><h3>Error al generar el QR</h3></center></div>';
    $('#response_qr').html(view);
    $('#on_qr').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#on_qr').text('Generar');
  } else if(r.error == false){
    view = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-fill alert-close alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">';
    view += '<center><h3>Codigo QR generado...Espera</h3></center></div>';
    $("#response_qr").html(view);
    setTimeout(function(){
      location.href='?view=qr';
    },2000);
  }
})
});
}
```

Esos son los scripts que estoy utilizando, la verdad no he podido conseguir el error. Gracias a quien me eche una mano!

Comment: El primer error es de lógica: **no mandes algo a validar en el servidor si lo puedes validar en el cliente**. Eso quiere decir que tienes todas las posibilidades de verificar que el formulario está vacío en el cliente, o sea, en Javascript/jQuery... ¿por qué lo mandas al servidor para que se valide?  Luego, la validación que haces en el servidor no funciona, porque la condición que pones para insertar es esta: `if(!file_exists($PathFinal)){...` pues resulta que sí, que ese archivo existe y entonces el `INSERT` ocurre. Cuando tú revisas en el `done` ...

Comment: lo de `empty`, aquí: `if(r.qr == 'empty'){` **es demasiado tarde** ... el código viajó al servidor (nunca debió haberlo hecho si el formulario estaba vacío) y encima se insertaron datos. Debes comprender que enviar datos al servidor supone un consumo de recursos importante, por eso, todo lo que puedas hacer del lado del cliente, hazlo, no se lo mandes al servidor. Si el servidor hablara te diría: ***¿para qué me mandaste esto, si no era válido? ¿por qué no lo bloqueaste en el cliente? ...¿Ahora tengo yo que decirte que lo que me mandaste estaba vacío?***

Comment: Entiendo @A.Cedano, ya me queda todo claro. Muchas gracias de verdad! Deberia existir la opcion de puntuar los comentarios tambien!

Comment: De hecho existe, una flecha gris que aparece cuando colocas el puntero a la izquierda de cada comentario.